# Buttons to filter order of <li>

Tags: vue.js

I have an application to list github users and theirs repos, Im using the GitHub API.
I can list the repositories but I need to make a checkbox option to filter them by rating (stars)

https://codesandbox.io/s/kw2zmqz6p5?fontsize=14

I have uploaded my code in Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/kw2zmqz6p5?fontsize=14

Now Im displaying the repositories list in some kind of order but I need to create a few filters like Order by Rating, or date...

Comment: What is it you want your code to do and how is its current functionality not right? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Right now its displaying the list of repositories but I need to create some filters like "order by Rating/Date..." and I dont know how to make it.

Comment: What you'll need to do is take `resultRepos` and sort them. When do you want them to be sorted? Immediately? On some user action? If the way they're sorted needs to change, it might be helpful to have a `sortedRepos` computed property. That computed property can then take in `this.resultRepos` and sort them by `this.sortBy` (a new data property that updates on... user click? checkbox selection?) and return the repos sorted however you want. Computed properties are useful for cases like this, because they update automatically, when their dependencies change.

Comment: @ebbishop I've just updated my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/oox0z910yz?fontsize=14 -  Im loading the repositories on button click, but in the second search I need to clear the last results to bring the new ones... How can I do it? And I still not ordering the results as I wish...